# Spring form validation not returing error message

Tags: java, forms, spring, bean-validation

I'm using the Spring beanvalidator to validate my posted form. This is the jsp code:

```
<div class="step-row">
<label for="telephone" class="text-label-medium">Telefoonnummer&nbsp;*</label>
<form:input id="telephone" path="telephone" maxlength="15" size="13" />
<form:errors path="telephone" cssClass="error"/>
</div>
```

My java form:

```
@NotNull
@NotBlank
@Length(max = 50, applyIf = "telephone is not blank")
private String telephone;
```

Code in my controller:

```
validator.validate(form, result);
     if (result.hasErrors()) {
     return mv;
}
```

When the input is wrong, it doesn't post the data. So that works. The only problem is it doenst put an error message at the form:error tag.

Comment: What kind of validator are you using ?

Comment: org.springmodules.validation.bean.BeanValidator

Answer (score 0):

instead of running the validator yourselve use

```
@RequestMapping
public ModelView handle(@Valid Form form, BindingResult result)
```

Comment: What is the difference? The validation is working already, but it's not returning the messages to my view.

Comment: You did not posted the code how you handle the validator. So I only want to make sure that this not shown coded causes the problem.